# Why do I get wrong date from timestamp?

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have `776635200` timestamp stored in database.

When I format it to string on server-side in php I get the following result:

`var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 776635200)); // string(19) 1994-08-12 00:00:00`

But when I do the same on client-side in JS I get the following result:

`console.log(new Date(776635200 * 1000))  // Thu Aug 11 1994 23:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (Ð·Ð¸Ð¼Ð°))`

Why do I get different result?

Comment: Looks like something related to Timezone.

Comment: Define "wrong". What's the *expected*, "correct" answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in php it's formatted with a different timezone, that is probably GMT+0400 while in JS it's formatted using the timezone GMT+0300.

Try to var dump the timezone in PHP.

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s O", 776635200));
```

Answer (score 1):

The server side takes its timezone settings from the location of the server and / or the PHP settings whilst the client side js takes its time settings from the local timezone set in the users computer. Which may be in a different timezone.

Comment: *from the location of the server* And/OR PHP Settings. +1 regardless

Comment: thanks @Hanky Panky - have amended my answer. :)